# If abelian $P\in{\rm Syl}_p(G)$, and $H\le P$ and $H^g\le P$, show $g\in G$ is the left product of an element of $N_G(P)$ with an element of $C_G(H)$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

> If abelian $P \in{\rm Syl}_p(G)$, and $H \leq P$ and $H^g \leq P$, show $g \in G$ is the left product of an element of $N_G(P)$ with an element of $C_G(H)$

First, I set $g=nc$, where I hope to find that $n \in N_G(P)$ and $c \in C_G(H)$. I am trying to do this by contradiction, assuming either $n \notin N_G(P)$ (which implies $n \notin N_G(H) )$ or $c \notin C_G(H)$. In the first cast ($n \notin N_G(P)$, $c \in C_G(H)$), we have that $H^g = (H^n)^c \neq H^c = H$. However, $g$ is arbitrary (as far as I know) in $G$, so I can not use that $P$ is abelian to find that $H^g = H$. I know that $P$ must be the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup but I can't see how that will help me.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It makes no sense to try to express $g$ that way; every element of a group can be expressed as a product in many, many ways, so there is not going to be any kind of uniqueness that you can try to leverage into obtaining what you hope.

Comment: Your first step is bound to fail; because suppose the conclusion were correct and you are able to express $g$ as $nc$, with $n$ in the normalizer, and $c$ in the centralizer. Pick $x$ that is not in the normalizer or the centralizer, and rewrite $g$ as $g=nc = (nx)(x^{-1}c)$, and now we have $g$ written as something not in the normalizer times something not in the centralizer. So even if the conclusion is correct, your approach cannot possibly get you there.  In addition, you have no warrant to claim that $P$ is the unique Sylow subgroup; that does not follow from the premises.

Comment: Hint: $P^{g^{-1}}$ and $P$ are both Sylow $p$-subgroups of $C_G(H)$, so they are conjugate in $C_G(H)$.

Comment: As Arturo Magidin pointed out in his (now deleted) answer, this argument appears to give $g = cn$ (with $c \in C_G(H)$ and $n \in N_G(P)$) rather than $g = nc$. (In fact I have never heard the expression "left product" before, and it could be interpreted to mean that the element in $C_G(H)$ goes on the left.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note.** I had run into an issue when writing this, then mistakenly assumed $g$ fixed $H$ set-wise and that got me the right expression and a couple of comments below. When I fixed that error, I could not get the expression of $g$ as a product in the order in which I interpret the original question to be requiring: the product of an element in the normalizer times an element in the centralizer. Derek Holt has given a counterexample to show that it may be impossible to achieve that; since he refers to my answer, I'm adding this note and undeleting.

---

Following on Derek Holt’s suggestion: note that $H\leq P$, and $H\leq P^{g^{-1}}$. Since $P$ is abelian, $P\leq C_G(H)$, and since $P^{g^{-1}}$ is also abelian, $P^{g^{-=1}}\leq C_G(H)$.

Now note that $P^{g^{-1}}$ and $P$ are both Sylow $p$-subgroups of $C_G(H)$ (you should prove this). Therefore, they are conjugate in $C_G(H)$; that is, there exists $c\in C_G(H)$ such that $P^{g^{-1}c}=P$. Therefore, $g^{-1}c\in N_G(P)$.

But that gives the wrong product order: $g^{-1}c\in N_G(P)$, so $c^{-1}g=n$ for some $N\in N_G(P)$, $g = cn$.

Comment: Why do we have that $H = H^g$?

Comment: We don't. I think that's a typo.

Comment: But he uses it in his answer when saying $P^g \leq C_G(H)$, no?

Comment: @user244685: Yeah; messed it up in trying to get the equation on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

In his (unfortunately deleted) answer, Arturo Magidin proved that $g = cn$ with $c \in C := C_G(H)$ and $n \in N:= N_G(P)$.

I have found a counterexample that shows that it is not necessarily the case that $g=nc$ for $c \in C$ and $n \in N$.

Let $G=A_7$ and $P = \langle (1,2,3), (4,5,6) \rangle \in {\rm Syl}_3(G)$, and let $H = \langle (1,2,3) \rangle \in P$.

Note that I am taking $H^g$ to mean $g^{-1}Hg$ and I compose permutations from left to right.

Then with $g = (1, 6)(2, 4)(3, 5, 7)$, we have $H^g = \langle (4,5,6) \rangle \le P$.

We have $g = cn$ with $c = (1, 3, 2)(4, 6)(5, 7) \in C$ and $n = (1, 4)(2, 5, 3, 6) \in N$, but it can be checked that $g \not\in NC$. (I checked this on the computer. Since $|NC|=|CN| = 144$, it could be tedious to check it by hand.)

Comment: I've added a note and undeleted, given the reference. Thanks for the counterexample; makes me feel better for running into a roadblock...